# Is there a C lib to find peaks in noisy data equivalent to findPeaks.m

Tags: c, signal-processing, smoothing

i have a noisy set of data and want to find the peaks in it. There is a matlab function for this exact task which includes smoothing of the data. I is called [findpeaks.m](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/findpeaks.m)

Now as im working in C i would either would have to code this by myself or use some functions which im not aware of. I hope you can tell me if they exist and where i can find them, as this is a very common problem.

To be clear what im searching of: a function to first smooth my data and then calculate the peaks, both preferably with some parameters for smoothing method, peak width etc.

Thanks!

Comment: http://spuc.sourceforge.net?

Comment: Take a look at the hotspot algorithm described here: http://www.encodeproject.org/ENCODE/encodeTools.html